# como adicionar dias na data em javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Olá, estou a tentar criar um formulario para somar dias na data para calcular o dia de saida do cliente mas quando faço a soma os formularioagem de forma estranha e nao me da a data suposta ou seja se adicionar 5 dias muda completamente a data de saida e não so nos dias

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="data_permanencia">Days to stay</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_permanecia" onchange="setSaida()" autocomplete="off" id="data_permanecia" placeholder="Dias">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputCity">Starting Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_entrada" name="data_entrada">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="data_saida">Leaving Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="data_saida" class="form-control"  name="data_saida" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
{
  var todaydate = new Date();
  var day = todaydate.getDate();
  var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
  var data_entrada = day + " / " + month + " / " + year;
  document.getElementById("data_entrada").value = data_entrada; 

  function setSaida(startDate,days){
   /* you might need a start date validation here... */
    var days = document.getElementById("data_permanecia").value;    
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(startDate.getDate()  + days);
    if(!isNaN(date)){
      document.getElementById("data_saida").value = date.getDate()+" / "+(date.getMonth()+1)+" / "+date.getFullYear();
    }
  }

  //listen to user's input
  const $source = document.querySelector('#data_permanecia');
  const typeHandler=function(e){
    setSaida(todaydate,e.target.value);
  }
  $source.addEventListener('input', typeHandler)
  $source.addEventListener('propertychange', typeHandler)

}
```

link para editar no code pen https://codepen.io/Sderdev/pen/NWqazLM?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na soma `startDate.getDate()  + days`, porque o valor `startDate.getDate()` é do tipo `number` e o valor `days` é do tipo `string`.

Então ele esta apenas concatenando valores, por exemplo:

```
1 + "1" = "11"


1 + 1 = 2
```

Quando ocorre essa soma errada e o valor dos dias passa ser maior que 31, o `setDate` do javascript tem a inteligencia de compreender que avançamos 1 mês e agora estamos no dia 1 do mês seguinte, devido a isso ocorre a mudança de dias e meses do seu `input`.

Para fazer a soma da maneira correta, você precisa transformar o valor `days` para o tipo `number`, dessa maneira:

```
date.setDate(startDate.getDate() + Number(days));
```

ou

```
date.setDate(startDate.getDate() + parseInt(days));
```

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito funcionou